# How to get c_str (for send) when string contains multiple NUL characters?

Tags: c++, string

I have string of more than *4 million* characters and I want to send this string via a socket. However, send () can only accept `const char`. I tried using `c_str()`.

My string contains more than one null terminator \0, therefore `c_str ()` does not work correctly. any idea how to delete or replace **\0**

Comment: no.  does send not also take a length?  There is nothing going on here which is interpreting your data.  char is the size of the buffer element, and len is the number of those elements being sent.  Imagine an internet where you could not send a zero...

Comment: What you should be thinking is,  "You should be able to send 4 million zeroes..."

Comment: You're doing something wrong in your code that you're not mentioning. There's no reason this shouldn't "just work". What evidence do you have that it's not working? What value does `send` return for the number of bytes sent? How many bytes does the other side recieve?

Comment: Tried send( sock, str.data(), str.length(), 0 ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\0'), str.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the length of the buffer you are sending in that same function. I'd also recommend breaking that 4MB buffer into smaller pieces and sending them one after the other, as there's probably a limit on the buffer size the `send` function allows.

Comment: I have already tried does not work, 
in other side i get a few character's as in original string.